# Should we embed special cases into business logic/algorithm or leave it separate?

Tags: coding-style

Consider I have some codes that use different logic for some special case, e.g.:

```
bool compareRatio(unsigned int a,unsigned int b,unsigned int x,unsigned int y){
    if(x==0){
        return false;
    }else if(y==0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return (float)a/x<(float)b/y;
    }
}
```

and to eliminate special case, I can rewrite it:

```
bool compareRatio(unsigned int a,unsigned int b,unsigned int x,unsigned int y){
    return a*y<b*x;
}
```

and for other similar situations such as searching in arrays with special case array size=0:

```
int[] a={1,4,2,7,5,1};
if(a.length == 0 ){
}else{
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    }
}
```

I can also rewrite it as:

```
int[] a={1,4,2,7,5,1};
for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
}
```

But my question is, should we tend to eliminate special case, or just leave it in the code? Or depend on cases? I think eliminate special case can reduce number of codes, but the codes become less straight forward. Alternatively, leaving special cases may make the code become ugly, but I think it is easier to maintain and can remind other programmers this business logic has some special conditions. Which style is preferred?

Comment: Depends on how special the special case is. There's no universal answer to this.

Comment: In the second example, I dont understand why you would even consider adding the special case? It doesn't do anything.

Comment: Careful with eliminating those `(float)` casts. Overflow might cause problems when you multiply two large positive numbers and get a negative one.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest correct code is almost always best. Document the expected behavior both in comments and in unit tests.  Your first example doesn't even have any special cases, and the simple "return a*y < b*x" is vastly preferable to the alternative. Then write a few unit tests, one with x and y zero, one with x zero, one with y zero, and three cases where a/x < b/y, a/x = b/y, a/x > b/y.

Answer (score 0):

I usually try to keep code as readable (= simple) as possible, so I try to eliminate such cases where possible.

So the question is: *when* is it possible? You definitely need those checks if they are part of the business logic (eg a balance check before reducing a bank account).
You don't if you can make assumptions (+ document those) on preconditions, eg parameter *v* must not be *null*.

In your first example you prevent an exception to be thrown due to a division by 0. This is good, because if a caller can provide 0 he probably does at some point. You wouldn't need the check if it would be very unlikely that in your context/application X becomes 0. That's a case for exception handling.

In your second example, you are just taking a shortcut. Both versions would behave the same way. So take the one, that is better readable/maintainable.